# What happens when the third str.replace() parameter is negative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, str-replace

Please explain what is happening here?

`print("banana".replace('a','1',-3))`

The output is :
`b1n1n1`

Comment: Negative counts replace all.  Some discussion here: https://bugs.python.org/issue39304

Comment: It's replacing everything. Why are you confused about what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ticket 5416](https://bugs.python.org/issue5416):

> The negative value was being used somewhat as a sentinel value to denote replace-all.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace, the code should act by only acting on the first (count) occurrences. When count is negative, this specification is meaningless, so the result is basically just an implementation detail.

> str.replace(old, new[, count]) Return a copy of the string with all
> occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument
> count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

In CPython, the docstring says

```
    """
    Return a copy with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.
    
      count
        Maximum number of occurrences to replace.
        -1 (the default value) means replace all occurrences.
    
    If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are
    replaced.
    """
```

Likely they are checking whether the number of replaced things is equal to your count by decrementing the count from the number you provide until it hits 0. If you start with -1 or any negative the internal counter will never hit 0, so in CPython any negative number effectively means "replace all".

Comment: Well, there's more to it, as explained in the link posted in the question's comments, and specifically in [this part](https://bugs.python.org/issue39304#msg359807)